# Does bash explicitly allow commands like passwd, su, etc., to run in setuid while disabling other custom binaries?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, security, c

I know that /bin/bash has certain built-in protections that prevent the abuse of the Set-UID mechanism. So if I create a custom binary and execute it, it won't run with SUID 0 (refer the below image). Then how does running *passwd* in bash shell runs with root privilege?

[image]

C code of system file in the above image:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    system("ls");
}
```

Comment: Do not post images when plain text will do.

Comment: Bash ignores the setuid bit on _itself_.  It doesn't care about the setuid bit of some random executable.

Comment: `system()` runs `/bin/sh`, and if that's Bash, there's your issue.

Comment: I'm not sure how many restrictions on setuid execution are implemented by Bash.  I think most of them are implemented in the Linux kernel.